# How to add a loading spinner to WooCommerce Checkout page

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a loading spinner .gif to the WooCommerce checkout page. It needs to appear after the submit payment button has been pressed.

I am currently using this code:

```
.checkout.woocommerce-checkout.processing {
background-image:url('https://wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/images/Preloader_2.gif');
background-position: 50% 84%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I am placing the code in `Woocommerce.min.css` and the preloader .gif is in the the file path as specified above.

The .gif isnt showing at all on checkout. I'm wondering if the `blockUI blockOverlay` is hiding it. I have tried to remove the blocking UI with:

`.blockUI.blockingOverlay {display: none;}` or to apply a `z-index` of `1001` to layer the .gif but also to no avail.

I have attached a screenshot of the `blockUI` in Firebug.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your custom CSS file:

```css
.woocommerce .blockUI.blockOverlay:before,
.woocommerce .loader:before {
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  /* This was on 90%, should be 50% */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -0.5em;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  -webkit-animation: none;
  -moz-animation: none;
  animation: none;
  background: url(".../path/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/images/select2-spinner.gif")
    center center;
  background-size: cover;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good plugin to use, https://codecanyon.net/item/wooloader/22355988.
You can able to upload and use your custom GIF/SVG loading spinner.
Cheers.!

Answer (score 0):

Try this below section.

Please copy the woo-commerce plugin folder (plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend) checkout.js and paste in your active theme folder and add following code in your function.php

and after then you can add your custom action in theme checkout.js file.

```
function so_27023433_disable_checkout_script(){
    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-checkout' );
    wp_enqueue_script('checkout',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/checkout.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so_27023433_disable_checkout_script' );
```